# Is the default margin for <body> tag deprecated in html5

Tags: html, margin, document-body

I have read in forums and in some old documentation, that there is a default [margin](/questions/tagged/margin) on the body tag of 8px. But on [This Site](https://html.com/tags/body/) I read that all the default styling attributes of [body](/questions/tagged/body) tag has been deprecated in [html5](/questions/tagged/html5).

But I found this default margin appearing in Firefox during an html5 practice session. Is it some specific issue with the browser, or it isn't deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers have supported `topmargin`, `leftmargin`, etc as **attributes** you could add to the `<body>` start tag to control margins.

These have never been part of any HTML specification. (If they had been, then they would have been deprecated in HTML 4). They are non-standard extensions to HTML introduced by browsers during the late '90s.

HTML 5 marks then as [non-conforming features](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) (which is not the same as deprecated, but the document you found conflates the two states).

The default *stylesheet* that browsers apply to HTML documents includes a margin for the body element. This is not deprecated (or mandated by any specification).